# No puedo imprimir el valor una $_Session con un echo

Tags: php, html, mysqli, session

Tengo un sistema de autentificación de login que es este:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['txtpass'])) 
{
    session_start();
    //variable de conexion: recibe dirección del host , usuario, contraseña y el nombre base de datos
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona") or die ("Error de conexion porque: ".$mysqli->connect_errno);
    // comprobar la conexión 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $login = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtlogin']);   
    $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);

    $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbusuario where login='$login' and pass='$pass' and activo!=0");
    $valida=$resultado->num_rows;
    if($valida != 0)
    {
        $datosUsu = $resultado->fetch_row();
        $_SESSION['nombreusu'] = $datosUsu[3];
        $_SESSION['perfil'] = $datosUsu[4];             
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=listar.php'>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 
        "<script> 
            var textnode = document.createTextNode('Usuario ó Password Incorrecto');
            document.getElementById('msg').appendChild(textnode);
        </script>";     
    }   
}

?>
```

Como veis, si acepto bien el login y pass , cojo dos valores de la tabla donde esta el login y pass y lo guardo en una variable session y voy a una paágina .php

```
$_SESSION['nombreusu'] = $datosUsu[3];
$_SESSION['perfil'] = $datosUsu[4];
```

Cuando paso a la siguiente página, que es listar.php, tengo esto:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['nombreusu']))
{

?>
<!----Todo el código----> 

<?php
}
 else
{
?>
     <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=index.php">
<?php
}
?>
```

Pues bien, dentro de "Todo el código" , quiero imprimir `$_SESSION['perfil']`

Y hago esto:

```
  <?php 
  $quieneres= $_SESSION['perfil']
  echo $quieneres;
  ?>
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fondomarino\listar.php on line 419
```

**¿Porque no puedo ver el valor por pantalla de la variable Session???**

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta el `;`al final de la primera línea, prueba así:

```
 <?php 
  $quieneres= $_SESSION['perfil'];
  echo $quieneres;
  ?>
```